A github commit is not deploying and has no green tick
Created a branch to fix a bug, which required 2 changes. Made the two changes, as separate commits. Opened a PR.
Deployed the branch, one of the changes is not in the deployed version. Odd.
Double check everything. Examine the file on that branch within Github, can see the change.
Look at the PR, there's no green 'tick' next to that commit. I don't know what that means.

I can't understand how the change can 100% be on the branch within github but not be deploying. Any ideas? What does the green tick mean?
I should add that the commit only changed a few words in a resource file from upper case to lower case. Could it be that it can't detect case changes somehow? Even though browsing to the file within github is showing the changes? Because the file would be the same size, just changing Hello to hello.

The ticks you see are from GitHub Actions or GitHub Pages (you can click on them) and in your case will visualize the status of your build/deployment. Depending on how Actions is configured in the workflow file, it will be triggered at different events. In your case is seems to run at every push against the branch you are making a PR from. If you push two commits at once, only the last commit will be picked up by GitHub Actions. The only weird thing is that upon deployment of the last commit (the green tick), it should also have taken up your previous changes from the commit that does not have a green tick.
I don't know your specific setup, but in most scenarios the deployment will only happen when you merge into master/main and not when you make the pull request. So it might be normal you do not yet see the changes. The checks you see in the PR are most of the time build/integrity checks.

Thanks, we have our own build and deploy pipelines, so I triggered the build pipeline and then the deploy pipeline. It could be something to do with the build pipeline but I'm not sure what or how to check that.

I don't think you have to manually trigger them but you can check in the .github/workflows folder of your repo. Here you can find the recipes for the workflows used to build and deploy. They will tell you what triggers them. Hi did you trigger them before and were you doing it on the right branch?

The build triggers automatically, but I tried running it manually and then deploying, somehow it's not picking up that commit. I'm stumped. I've created a new branch and off main and put just that file in, created a PR, and it has a green tick. So I'm at a loss.

That it has a green tick is a expected since you made a push. In order for me to understand the problem you will have to be more specific and not talk about thicks but which workflows were run (by clicking on the thics) and from which branch you triggered the dpeloyment yourself. What does the Actions tab tell you?

Actions tab just contains CodeQL actions. It seems the problem was that somewhere, something couldn't detect that only the capitalisation had changed. I made a whole new branch, and manually put the same changes in (changing 'SomeWords' to 'somewords', built and deployed it. The site still said 'SomeWords'. I made it 'somewords TEST' on the end and redeployed, and it worked. Then I removed the TEST, and redeployed, and ended up with 'somewords'. I can't imagine what step is not detecting or deploying that capitalisation change, but it did fix the problem doing this.

This seems to be a problem caused by the deployment pipeline and not related to GitHub.
